# XML to database with Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have given a XML file. I want to store a subset of the content of this file in a relational database.

I could use a framework like `JAXB` to convert the content of the xml file into Java POJOs and write them to database (e.g. with `Hibernate`).

But is there a built-in opportunity in `Hibernate` to do this without using a additional framework like `JAXB`?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Not intended as an answer, but check [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3) for making JAXB objects JPA-able. **Disclaimer**: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there was an XML mapping feature in Hibernate 3:

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html

However this feature was noted as "experimental". And I don't see it in Hibernate 4 or 5:

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can't find it too. Then the only way is XML -> POJO -> Database, or do you know an other way?

Comment: @mrbela Not with Hibernate. I'd actually do XML->DTO->Entities->Database. See also EclipseLink/MOXy (but that's POJO-centric). My Hyperjaxb is another option. And there's plenty of approaches of getting XML into relational database more-or-less structurally.